# Смена содержимого блока при наведении курсора (Angular)

Tags: angular

Есть набор блоков, добавляемых через *ngFor. Как сделать, чтобы при наведении курсора на блок, срабатывали индивидуальные события (mouseover) и (mouseout) для одного блока. На данный момент содержимое меняют все блоки

```js
@Component({
   selector: 'app-main',
   templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
   public isChangedBlock = false;
   public itemPrefix: Array<string> = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.split('');
    constructor() {}
}
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let item  of items; let i = index"
     (mouseover)="isChangedBlock = true"
     (mouseout)="isChangedBlock = false">
   <span [hidden]="isChangedBlock">text {{itemPrefix[i]}}</span>
   <span [hidden]="!isChangedBlock">icon</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот так сработает:

```
@Component({
   selector: 'app-main',
   templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
   public changedBlockIndex: number | null;
   public itemPrefix: Array<string> = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.split('');
    constructor() {}
}
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let item  of items; let i = index"
     (mouseover)="changedBlockIndex = i"
     (mouseout)="isChangedBlockIndex = null">
   <span [hidden]="changedBlockIndex === i">text {{itemPrefix[i]}}</span>
   <span [hidden]="changedBlockIndex !== i">icon</span>
</div>
```

В целом, прятать/показывать блоки при помощи JS - это слегка тормозное решение, подверженное ошибкам при динамическом изменении массива.

Когда дело доходит до логики спрятать/показать по наводке мыший, старайтесь решать это на чистом CSS. Как-то так:

```
<div *ngFor="let item  of items; let i = index" class="block">
   <span class="text">text {{itemPrefix[i]}}</span>
   <span class="icon">icon</span>
</div>
```

```css
.block .text {
  display: none;
}

.block .icon {
  display: block;
}

.block:hover .text {
  display: block;
}

.block:hover .icon {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: я не подразумеваю кого-то оскорбить, не хочешь - не общайся, но не стоит вводить людей в заблуждение, если ты не обладаешь достаточным кол-вом информации, фразу `убогое решение, жрущее память и производящее тонны ошибок.` лучше просто удалить, отредактировав ответ, я тогда удалю свои комментарии :) если ты мог заметить - я не реагирую на другие теги кроме "angular", потому что знаю, что буду, например в теге "react" выглядеть глупо, если дам ответ основанный на своих внутренних предрассудках. Точно также если зайду в тег "си" и дам там ответ, мне сразу влепят кучу минусов и засмеют. Мир :)

Comment: Поправил. Убрал про убогое, но в целом js решение медленее чем css-решение. И производит проблемы, будучи применено к динамичемки-меняющемуся массиву. Так нормально?

Comment: лучше :) оно медленнее только с таким подходом, я знаю как сделать так чтобы не было медленно, но для этого нужно лезть в дебри зон и тд... что вряд ли нужно автору :D НО, для массива `'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.split('')` это не имеет значения, можно просто сказать, что данном случае с помощью CSS можно уменьшить количество работы, возлагаемой на JS и сделать это декларативнее через пару строчек стилей) ИМХО звучит красивее :D пока поставлю плюс)

Comment: сбасибо, бро :)